# Displaying variables using gui in Unity

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, unityscript

In my game, I want a button that when clicked on, overwrites a string. This string will then be displayed in some text above. So far it is going very wrong...

Here is the code ( in C#) that I use:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ConnectGUI : MonoBehaviour {
private string map = "No map selected.";

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}
void OnGUI () {
    GUI.Label(new Rect(10,10,200,90), "Map selected: ", map);
    if(GUI.Button (new Rect(10,50,90,20), "Pier")){
        map = "Pier";
        }
    }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made a mistake in following line:

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(10,10,200,90), "Map selected: ", map);
```

should be

```
GUI.Label(new Rect(10,10,200,90), "Map selected: " + map);
```

Change the comma `,` to a plus `+`;