# MORE scripting problems in Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, error-handling

Backing up my previously answerd question ([Displaying variables using gui in Unity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31007997/displaying-variables-using-gui-in-unity)), I would like some help solving MORE problems! I'm getting an error saying

> Cannot implicitly convert type string to bool.

Here is the (adapted) code that I use:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class ConnectGUI : MonoBehaviour {
//Variables
string Map;
string Gamemode;
//Var set
void Start () {
    Map = "No map selected!";
    Gamemode = "No game mode selected!";
}
//Configurable settings.
void OnGUI () {
    //Map GUI
    GUI.Box(new Rect(10,10,200,90), "Map selected: "+ Map);
    if(GUI.Button (new Rect(10,50,90,20), "Pier")){
        Map = "Pier";
    }
    //Game mode GUI
    GUI.Box (new Rect(350,10,250,90), "Mode selected: "+ Gamemode);
    if(GUI.Button (new Rect (375,50,125,20), "Team Deathmatch")){
        Gamemode = "Team Deathmatch";
    }
}
//ConnectToServer
void Connect () {
    if (Map = "Pier"){
        if (Gamemode = "Team Deathmatch") {
            Application.LoadLevel("Pier TeamDM");
        }
    }

}

}
```

Any ideas to solving this error?

P.S: If you're wondering why the `connect()` function isn't called, it's because it is called through unity's new UI system.

Comment: And on which line is that bool property that you try to assign a string?

Comment: Include stack trace. Which line is causing the error.

Comment: Can you give us the full error message, especially including which of the lines above is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a typo. Map = "Pier" - assaing value "Peir" to variable Map. Should be 
Map=="Peir". But to compare strings you shold use String.Equals

```
void Connect () {
if (Map.Equals("Pier")){
    if (Gamemode.Equals( "Team Deathmatch")) {
        Application.LoadLevel("Pier TeamDM");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain C# overloads the "==" operator so you don't have to call .Equals like you have to in Java

Comment: You right C# overloads. But using String.Equals allows you to catch a situation when you make a decision  with nested if and one of input strings variable would be null. If you use == you will have strange behavior, if you use String.Equals you will have an exception. BTW Equals faster than == sometimes.

Comment: @vsenik I shall bare these tips in mind when coding in the future (for Unity C#)